# in case of multiple outbound calls, how to identify the call uniquely

Tags: twilio

I am creating a voice survey application so that the the users can complete the survey over voice using the DTMF inputs.
I am creating multiple calls at a given moment, but i get the call information only when the call connects and the user send the DTMF.

Is there a way, i map the received DTMF input with a unique outgoing call ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create an outbound call [the object that is returned includes a `sid` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties) that is the unique identifier for that call resource within Twilio. That [sid will be present in the webhook requests as the `CallSid` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters). So, if you store the initial call sid against your user somehow, you can always look it up using the information in the incoming webhook request.